# Hello Need Help placing a second JButton in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

Hello and  Thank you for any responses beforehand. I am a beginner to programming with Java and have decide to make a basic J Frame with a few buttons. I am struggling with resolving this problem on my own and when to get it figured out before I continue to the next step.  Below I have a written some code of a J Frame, I have both buttons placed where I want them but when I added the second button it overlapped over the first button. I am wondering if i am approaching this in the right way and how I can improve it.

```
    Frame guiWindow = new Frame();
    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("A");
    JPanel pnlButton2 = new JPanel();
    JButton btnAdd2 = new JButton("B");

    public Frame1() {    

        //Button 1
        pnlButton.setLayout(null);
        btnAdd.setBounds(40, 300, 100, 50);  
        pnlButton.setBounds(40, 300, 50, 50);
        pnlButton.add(btnAdd);
        add(pnlButton);           

        //Button2        
        pnlButton2.setLayout(null);
        btnAdd2.setBounds(260, 300, 100, 50);  
        pnlButton2.setBounds(260, 300, 100, 50);
        pnlButton2.add(btnAdd2);
        add(pnlButton2);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setTitle("Pratice");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're new, which is quite understandable as to why this occurred. First thing to know, when you add a JPanel into a JFrame; unless you're doing some kind of positioning or something needed, you only add one JPanel. Thats probably why it overlaps. You are trying to add one thing, and then another in the same region. All you need to do is take pnlButton2 out, and use pnlButton as the main way of adding your buttons :) You could also use a layout manager called GridLayout. That is probably something very confusing, but I can explain:

GridLayout is a way of creating a grid effect on the JFrame or any type of frame that holds items. It will align your buttons in a grid of your chosen size.

Here is a link to help explain more : [GridLayout - Oracle Java Helper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

But here is some code to explain what I was talking about with the JPanels and stuff :)

Hope I helped you, and didn't confuse you

```
Frame guiWindow = new Frame();
JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("A"); 
//JPanel pnlButton2 = new JPanel(); not needed :)
JButton btnAdd2 = new JButton("B");

public Frame1() {


//Button 1

pnlButton.setLayout(null);
btnAdd.setBounds(40, 300, 100, 50);  
pnlButton.setBounds(40, 300, 50, 50);
pnlButton.add(btnAdd);
pnlButton.add(btnAdd2); // see how we add the second button?
add(pnlButton);

/* remove this section
//Button2        
pnlButton2.setLayout(null);
btnAdd2.setBounds(260, 300, 100, 50);  
pnlButton2.setBounds(260, 300, 100, 50);
pnlButton2.add(btnAdd2);
add(pnlButton2);
*/




setSize(400, 400);
setTitle("Pratice");
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
}
```